# What is most common locale configuration for Latin america and Spain in JSF and PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jsf

When programming in JSF with PostgreSQL, There are some configurations to do when programming in an internazional software like:

- Numbers as Currency (Locale)
- Characters (support ñ)

What locale configuration do you considerate before start a project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get locale for Spain use "es_ES", but there are many locales for Latin america. I mean Peru uses "es_PE", Paraguay uses "es_PY" and so on. Please check this link to know more about locales, http://www.webreference.com/programming/Globalize-Web-Applications12_Java/index.html

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a specific locale for "Latin American Spanish", you can use es_419. Here are more details about that locale: http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/es-419/index.html

Comment: Thanks, this is another way

Comment: This is the correct answer (at least in general... perhaps not for PostgreSQL) See here: http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_code and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UN_M.49